# Обновление состояния редко изменяемых таблиц

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеем алгоритм, который использует набор правил, который хранится в таблице MS SQL Server. Если переданные на вход параметры `a,b,c` совпали с хранящимися в таблице - будь добр, верни то, что хранится в поле d таблицы. Это для простоты, реально в базе в таблице `RulesTree` лежит отображение весьма раскидистого дерева правил, и каждый раз рекурсивно строить это дерево нет никакого желания - лишние запросы к БД, лишние расчеты et cetera. По грубым оценкам, с построением дерева алгоритм работает 5 секунд, без построения - 1 секунду, и это не на самой слабой системе.

Алгоритм реализуем в форме WCF-сервиса `ValidationSerice`. В static constructor сервиса вызываем метод `pubic void RefreshCliassifiers()`, который строит дерево правил, и сохраняет его в `static List<RulesList> rulesList`.
Работу с базой ведем через EF.
Но правила имеют свойства меняться. Под это дело есть отдельный интерфейс, изменять который нельзя (т.е. мы не можем вызывать RefreshClassifiers или сохранять в базе итоговый набор правил в требуемом нашему алгоритму виде). Ну и классификатор, увы, не один. Меняются они редко, но меняются.

Вопросов два:
1. Нужно ли вообще в данном случае хранить дерево как `static List<RulesList> rulesList`, или есть другие варианты?
2. Как выяснить, что в таблицу `RulesTree` внесли изменения без перестроения списка правил?

**Обновление:** Попробовал через `SqlDependency`. Подготовил БД:

```
ALTER DATABASE [testbase] SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate;;
  CREATE QUEUE CntQueue;
  CREATE SERVICE CntChangeNotifications
  ON QUEUE CntQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostQueryNotification]);
```

Проверяю следующим кодом и ловлю run-time exception: Если `SqlDependency` используется без указания значения для Оptions, то перед выполнением команды, добавленной в экземпляр SqlDependency, необходимо вызвать метод `SqlDependency.Start()`.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connString = "Server=(local);Database=testbase;User Id=developeruser;Password=developerpassword;";
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString, "CntQueue");
    var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = "select * from cnt",
        Notification = null,
        Connection = new SqlConnection(connString)
    };
    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand);
    sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
    SqlDependency.Start(connString, "CntQueue");
    dependency.OnChange += OnChange;
    sqlCommand.ExecuteReader(); //!!!Exception!!!

    while (!changed)
    {
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Changed!");
    Console.ReadKey();
    SqlDependency.Stop(connString, "CntQueue");
}

private static bool changed = false;

private static void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    changed = true;
}
```

Но я же вызываю `SqlDependency.Start()`? Чего-то еще не хватает?
  exception.ToString():

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Если SqlDependency используется без указания значения для Оptions, то перед выполнением команды, добавленной в экземпляр SqlDependency, необходимо вызвать метод SqlDependency.Start().
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.GetDefaultComposedOptions(String server, String failoverServer, IdentityUserNamePair identityUser, String database)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CheckNotificationStateAndAutoEnlist()
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   в System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   в ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) в c:\csharp\projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:строка 33
```

UPD2. Заработал в итоге такой вариант:

```
        SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(sqlCommand, "Service=CntChangeNotifications;", 31557600);
```

Comment: А не подойдёт ли такая стратегия? (1) прочитать и закешировать в памяти дерево, (2) подписаться на изменения таблиц при помощи [`SqlDependency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), (3) при приходе нотификации инвалидировать кэш и перестроить его при следующем запросе к дереву.

Comment: Хм, интересно. В документации написано, что сначала нужно инициализировать SqlDependency, а только потом создавать SqlConnection. Может, проблема в этом?

Comment: Пробовал делать `SqlDependency.Start` сразу после `SqlDependency.Stop` - тот же результат.

Comment: А дайте, пожалуйста, полный текст Exception'а, а? И если можно через `ex.ToString()`, а не `ex.Message` (первый вариант включает вложенные исключения).

Comment: Добавил текст исключения

Comment: Нашёл английский текст: _When using SqlDependency without Providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance._

Comment: Да, оно самое, этот текст я тоже находил.

Comment: Вот [тут](http://forums.asp.net/t/1699287.aspx?SqlDependency+Start+Exception) говорят, что проблема была устранена конфигурированием сервера. (Если вы разбираетесь в базах данных, этот текст, может быть, прояснит что-то для вас.)

Comment: О, [вот ещё](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f77c989-d6de-49bf-9e4c-d24a60c0160f/net-20-sqldependency?forum=adodotnetdataproviders): _Not every SQL construct can be used with query notifications. ... Use of *, as in "SELECT * FROM Table"_,

Comment: Увы, не помогло. Ни замена * на список полей, ни добавление схемы.

Comment: Там же: _I found out the problem. When we create the SqlDependency object, the service name and the timeout values has to be passed as an argument to the constructor. `SqlDependency dependency =new SqlDependency(command,"Service=.;",1);`_

Comment: И следом: `SqlDependency mDependency = new SqlDependency(objCommand, null, 31557600); // listen for changes for 1 year` _The third parameter is the number of seconds after which the listener will expire (timeout). Thus, using a value '1' for the third parameter will cause an expiry message to be sent almost immediately!_

Comment: Заработало, огромное спасибо. Нужно явно указывать созданный в SQL Server сервис . Если не затруднит - оформите первый комментарий как ответ.

Comment: Ага, сейчас сделаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следующая стратегия должна подойти:

1. Прочитать и закешировать в памяти дерево
2. Подписаться на изменения таблиц при помощи [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. При приходе нотификации инвалидировать кэш и перестроить его при следующем запросе к дереву.