# Можно ли отлавливать изменения в БД?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

Например, в БД хранится какое-то расписание, которое может пополняться.

Может ли программа узнать, что в бд что-то поменялось (Например, в какую-то таблицу что-то добавилось), что бы со своей стороны сделать какое-то действие?

Если да, то как какими средствами это делается и на сколько это ресурсоемко для БД?

Если у Entity Framework есть какой-то удобны механизм, то хотелось бы расмотреть как это делается средствами Entity Framework и без него.

И хотелось бы с примерами. На примере, какой-нибудь абстрактной БД с двумя таблицами.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423033/13996 - оно?

Comment: @Zufir, думаю подойдет.

Comment: @Zufir,А эта штука не будет сильно грузить SQLServer?

Comment: Не замечал. Но у меня эти таблицы меняются ну оооочень редко :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно на задачу "проверить что что-то добавилось", вешают запрос на проверку MAX(id) и сверяют старое значение с новым.

Если требуется проверять, что что-то изменилось, создаете в базе данных поле на каждую запись updated_at, вешаете на нее индекс (для производительности), каждые n-времени проверяете нужные таблицы с помощью запроса **SELECT MAX(updated_at) FROM table**, и если он отличается от старого - делаете свои действия. Можете удобно например показывать какие записи изменились, просто взяв все записи где **updated_at** больше определенного значения.

Поле **updated_at** также можно использовать, как и в случае с id, если не требуется разделять добавлена ли новая запись или отредактирована. Достаточно просто его заполнять при добавлении записи, а не только при обновлении.

Данный запрос будет очень быстро работать за счет устройства работы индексов, но если таких запросов много, то лучше наверное как-то отдавать это через API, которое бы кешировало результаты на некоторое время.

В целом это самое **простое и адекватное архитектурное решение**, некоторые люди создают TRIGGER на обновление таблиц, и если таблица обновлена, пишут в другую таблицу дату последнего обновления и сверяют ее с прошлой, кто-то вообще проверяет контрольную сумму у таблицы или у файла таблицы.